# failed to load the given url using css background in codeigniter

Tags: css, codeigniter, background-image

I have a problem in loading my image, i got an error when i go to page source. The error it was saying is : Failed to load the given URL. When i copy the url and paste it in a browser, the image URL works fine. How can i solve this?

Here is the image of the error
[image: ERROR IMAGE]

Here is the path of my codeigniter picture

[image]

Comment: Check the relative path of image

Comment: @Jyothi Babu Araja the path works fine sir. when i copy the path and paste it in the browser, the image comes out

Comment: try giving the relative path as below

Comment: You need to set your base url in config.php **must** Like `$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/yourproject/';` other wise some css and images will not work properly

Comment: Try not using hardcoded url's ever, this will not work once you move to a production server. Next to that, I believe the correct path for your css file should be `url('/asset/uploaded_images/togoru.jpg')`

Answer (score 0):

Try giving the relative path like

```
url("../uploaded_images/toguru.jpg")
```

Comment: url("../uploaded_images/togoru.jpg") .. also saying failed to load image sir

Comment: what is the location of `custom.css` file ?

Comment: there at asset/css/custom.css, but i put it directly in my view, with div style=""

Comment: what do you mean sir ?

Comment: can you give the browser `url` which working for you to load image?

Answer (score 0):

try yoursite/(projectname)/asset/uploaded_images/togoru.jpg